# sencha touch dateFormat not working?

Tags: javascript, date, sencha-touch, touch, date-format

i'm very new to sencha touch and i have a problem with the dateFormat.

So, here is some code, i wrote:

First of all I have a datepickerfield to choose a date.

```
        var activityDateCreator = {
        xtype: 'datepickerfield',
        destroyPickerOnHide: true,
        name: 'date',
        label: 'Datum',
        dateFormat: 'd.m.Y',
        value: new Date(),
        picker: {
            yearFrom: 2013,
            yearTo: 2014
        },
        required: true
    };
```

At this point the dateFormat is displayed, how i want it to be.

The date is saved in the localStorage.

the model does look like that:

```
Ext.define('RMA-App.model.Activity', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'sport', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'date', type: 'date' , dateFormat: 'd.m.Y'},
        { name: 'time', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'street', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'place', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'comments', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'save', type: 'boolean'},
        { name: 'latitude', type: 'number'},
        { name: 'longitude', type: 'number' }
    ],
    validations:[
        { type: 'presence', field: 'id' },
        { type: 'presence', name: 'date'},
        { type: 'presence', name: 'name', message: "Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen an!"},
        { type: 'presence', name: 'time', message: "Bitte geben Sie eine Zeit an!"},
        { type: 'format', name: 'time', matcher: /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/, 
        message: "Bitte stellen Sie sicher, dass sie die Zeit im richtigen Format angeben. <br>Beispiel: 08:30"},
        { type: 'presence', name: 'street', message: "Bitte geben Sie die Straße für den Treffpunkt an!"}

    ]
}
```

});

Now i want to show the date in a textfield, which is not in the same view as the datepicker.

> ```
>     var activityDate = {
>         xtype: 'textfield',
>         name: 'date',
>         label: 'Datum',
>         readOnly: true
>     };
> ```

in the browser i can see the date, but it's shown like this: 
'Fri Aug 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)' 
instead of this: '23.08.2013'

Hope someone has a solution for my problem.

ps.: i'm sorry for my poor english :p

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `Fri Aug 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)` format into `23.08.2013`.

**In Extjs**

```
var date = new Date('Fri Aug 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)');
console.log(Ext.Date.format(date, 'd.m.Y'));
```

**In pure Javascript**

```
var date = new Date('Fri Aug 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)');
var curr_date = date.getDate();
var curr_month = date.getMonth() + 1; 
var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
console.log(curr_date + "." + curr_month + "." + curr_year);
```

Comment: @vishwa could you please throw some light on this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247016/edm-datetime-coversion-javascript